# Update Postgis MULTIPOINT through ActiveRecord Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgis

I am using [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) to work with `Postgis`.
I have a table schema as:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.multi_point :positions, using: :gist

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

From rails console, I have inserted the record as:

```
loc = Location.create(name: 'Kathmandu', positions: 'MULTIPOINT([-122 47],[-121 46])')
```

I want to update `positions` by adding new POINT. So,that `loc.positions` would be `MULTIPOINT([-122 47],[-121 46], [-119 45])`

So, How can i add new POINT in MULTIPOINT using ActiveRecord with `activerecord-postgis-adapter`.

Comment: I use LINESTRING instead of MULTILINE and we can easily add new point to LINESTRING.